# How to hide program names on KDE panel

Tags: kde, panel

In KDE or Plasma or whatever they're calling it now, programs on the panel show the name as well as the icon. I would like to hide the name so it just shows the icon but I couldn't find how to anywhere.

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you! I didn't realize those applications were a widget themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default [Panel](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Panels/en) in KDE Plasma Desktop is a widget container.
I assume the list of icons/names you are referring to is the "Task Manager" widget. Unfortunately it appears not to be configurable to only show icons, you'll have to choose a different widget.

Thanks to this [forum thread](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/display-icons-only-in-kde-plasma-taskbar-4175612158/): right-click on the Panel, click "Unlock Widgets", right-click on the Panel again. You should get a drop-down list that includes "Alternatives", one of which is "Icons-only Task Manager".